# jQuery AutoComplete field won't work, how can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

I want to make a jQuery field which will autocomplete the username when I type it, here's my code:

First comes my jQuery script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#search').typeahead({
            source: function(query, process) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'func/autocomplete.php'
                    type: 'POST';
                    data: 'query=' + query;
                    dataType: 'JSON';
                    async: true;
                    success: function(data) {
                        process(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Second comes the form:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="ribbon">Change player's IP(UCP Whitelist)</div>
    <table border="1" cellspacing="15" align="center">
        <tr>
            <form action='func/changeip.php' method='POST' class="navbar-search">
                <td><input type='text' class="search-query span3 pull-right" placeholder='Account Name' name='username' id='search' data-provide="typeahead"></td>
                <td><input type='text' placeholder='ex. 192.162.1.20' name='ip' id='ip'></td>
                <td><input type='submit' value='Change IP'></td>
            </form>
        </tr>
    </table>    
</div>
```

Third comes my autocomplete.php:

```
<?php
include '../includes/connect.php';

if (isset($_POST['query'])) {
    $query = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['query']);
    $sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE Username LIKE '%{$query}%'");
    $array = array();

    while ($row = fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        $array[] = $row['Username'];
    }

    echo json_encode($array);
}    
?>
```

Now, to put it straight. It simple doesn't work. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Your `form` element needs to be wrapping the whole `table`.

Comment: Are you including the typeahead lib?  autocomplete is not native to the core jQuery package

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:
Your script should look like this:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#search").on("keyup", function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'func/autocomplete.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: {query: $(this).val()},
                        success: function(data) {
                            process(data); 
                        }
                    });
              });
            });
    </script>
```

And in your PHP file please add on the first line of file this:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Here are two files that will help you understand the process. Replicate them and test to see they work.
**stackoverflow.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#search").on("keyup", function(){
                    var searchedText = $(this).val();
                    if (searchedText.length>=2){
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'stack_autocomplete.php',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: {query: $(this).val()},
                            success: function(data) {
                                 $("#search").val(data);
                            }
                        });
                   }
              });
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="ribbon">Change player's IP(UCP Whitelist)</div>
        <table border="1" cellspacing="15" align="center">
            <tr>
                <form action='func/changeip.php' method='POST' class="navbar-search">
                    <td><input type='text' class="search-query span3 pull-right" placeholder='Account Name' name='username' id='search' data-provide="typeahead"></td>
                    <td><input type='text' placeholder='ex. 192.162.1.20' name='ip' id='ip'></td>
                    <td><input type='submit' value='Change IP'></td>
                </form>
            </tr>
        </table>    
    </div>
</body>
```

and **stack_autocomplete.php**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$array = array("ana","alex","andrei");
$answer = "Nothing found.";
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($value,$_POST['query'])!==false) $answer = $value;
}
echo json_encode($answer);
exit();
?>
```

Please put these two files in your test directory and access **stackoverflow.php**. Then type in search box one of these names: alex | ana | andrei

Comment: @Pavel Nozharov Has this answer helped you ? Please answer here if you need more explanations.